# Pygame and Anaconda

Tags: python, pygame, anaconda

I am trying to download pygame, but knowing I am running on Anaconda, I tried to pass by their site.
I saw that I had to use the command "conda install -c pygame", it didn't work.
I tried `conda install -c Jo_Byr cogsci pygame` (Jo_Byr is my username on Anaconda), didn't work either.
Then it was turn of `conda install -c jonat cogsci pygame` (jonat is my computer username), and all variants with jonat, Jo_Byr or none as username and pygame or cogsci pygame for the package, but nothing worked.
I can send screenshots of the anaconda prompt cmd if necessary, just tell me which one.
Thanks in advance, sorry if someone already spoke of this issue, I didn't find anything about it.

Comment: I forgot to say hi sorry, and can't edit i dunno why

Comment: Please provide error messages

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before. I tried many commands but no results I got. then I downloaded pygame file separately and install it via cmd or terminal.these files are usually with an extension of .whl or wheel. just google it and find all the libraries u need.

Comment: Tanks for your answer. I also tried this, but didn't work. I guess that it is my fault, i'm not used to install things via cmd, and there are so much versions of pygame, i probably downloaded one wihch didn't fit with my computer.
I actually am running on the latest version o python (i think it is 4.0.1), is there a pygame version for this python version or do i need to go back to a 3.X version of python ?

Answer (score 0):

Installing conda packages has nothing to do with your computer or anaconda username.

The general syntax is `conda install <package name>`. The `-c` flag is used to specify the channel, which is a fancy name for the remote directory hosting the package. Different channels can host different versions of the same package e.g for pygame I use the package hosted by the `evindunn` channel, which can be obtained by

```
conda install -c evindunn pygame`
```

The `cogsci` channel just happens to be the channel with the highest downloads for the pygame package

Not specifying the channel tells conda to look for the package amongst the default set of channels, which can be found at https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/

Comment: _The cogsci channel just happens to be the channel with the highest downloads for the pygame package_ Unfortunately it hasn't been updated in over 3 years, this may be one of those cases where it's worth using pip.